# Alphabets-only MFC editbox

Tags: visual-c++, editcontrol

I have a Dialog-based applicaton which consist of 3 editboxes which are of CString type. The editboxes are for Firstname, Middlename and Lastname. My editboxes are Alphanumeric since all are of type CString.  Now my question is how can I validate my editboxes to accept only alphabets as an input? Is there any Dailog Data Validation routine to perform the validation?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at which DDV_... routines MFC implements, you'll see that there is no validation routine for checking that a string only contains alphanumeric characters. You will need to write your own DDV_xxx validation routine.

With Visual Studio 2010 for example you can look at `\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\dlgdata.cpp` and take the MFC validation routines as a starting point for writing your own validation routine.